# Passing a Javascript variable as model for a PartiaView in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a PartialView that should receive a model like:

`@model MiniSIGEweb.Models.StudentViewModel`

And I have this model as a javascript variable `viewModel.selectedStudent`:

```
<script>
        var viewModel = kendo.observable({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            selectedStudent: {},
            /*...*/
        });
    /*...*/
    </script>
```

How can I pass this variable to the PartialView?

```
@Html.Partial("_Edit.Mobile", /*Here I should pass the variable*/)
```

I'm not sure if this is important but I'm appending the StudentViewModelClass:

```
public class StudentViewModel
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(1, 100)]
        public Nullable<int> Age { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Course { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "School")]
        public string SchoolName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> BuildDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix server and client code. I can give you two ways how it could be achieved:

- Use client templating, for example [jsrender](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/demos.html)
- Use Ajax to load data from server (Action will return
  `PartialViewResult`)

From your question it's not clear which one is better.